# 'var' is null on at least one execution path - sonarqube or is it?

Tags: c#, foreach, sonarqube

While analyzing my code using sonarqube I came across `variableProducerAgreements` is null on at least one execution path in the following code (the `foreach` loop):

```
public List<string> GetVariableBrokerDealers(WebUserProfile userProfile, bool IsActingAsDelegate)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        IEnumerable<ProducerAgreement> variableProducerAgreements;

        if (userProfile?.ProducerProfile == null)
            return result;
        if (IsActingAsDelegate && userProfile.ProducerProfile.IsInactiveProducer)
        {
            variableProducerAgreements = userProfile.ProducerProfile?.ProducerAgreements.FindAll(ag => ag.IsActive && ag.IsVariableBranchContract);
        }
        else
        {
            variableProducerAgreements = userProfile.ProducerProfile?.ActiveAgreements.Where(a => a.IsVariableContract);
        }

        foreach (var agreement in variableProducerAgreements)
        {
            var originatingAgreement = agreement.GetOriginatingAgreement();
            if (originatingAgreement == null || originatingAgreement.ContractType != ContractType.VariableBD)
                continue;

            result.Add(originatingAgreement.AgentRepId);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

However, upon looking at it and trying various things, `variableProducerAgreements` seems to never be null in this `foreach` loop. During a code review, I'm being told that it can "totally" be null and should add conditional logic to handle it, but I'm not understanding how it can be null and thus not sure how to add a conditional. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a way in which `variableProducerAgreements` could be null since you have the null guard in place at the top (and assuming you don't have any crazy code in your property getters).

```
if (userProfile?.ProducerProfile == null)
    return result;
```

The `Where` and `FindAll` methods in .NET doesn't return null.

However, it is possible the use of a null-conditional every time you access `ProducerProfile` is confusing some tools and people. Since you're returning early if it is null, you should remove them:

```
if (IsActingAsDelegate && userProfile.ProducerProfile.IsInactiveProducer)
{
    variableProducerAgreements = userProfile.ProducerProfile.ProducerAgreements.FindAll(ag => ag.IsActive && ag.IsVariableBranchContract);
}
else
{
    variableProducerAgreements = userProfile.ProducerProfile.ActiveAgreements.Where(a => a.IsVariableContract);
}
```

If there was a way for it to be null before the if statement, you would also risk a `NullReferenceException` when you access the `IsInactiveProducer` property.

Also, the reviewer should be able to explain his/her reasoning.